Happiness in meditation
Things like sex or alcohol or drugs gives us pleasure because it shuts the conscious mind . But when doing meditation does we get happiness because of shutting of conscious mind / no thought ?
I mean what's the difference between the two ?

In Buddhism, sex or alcohol or drugs are called 'sensual pleasures'. Meditation pleasure is called 'non-sensual pleasure'. Please refer to AN 2.64–76 about the different types of pleasure or happiness; which are each summarized as two types of happiness.
The mechanism of pleasure is the same for both types of pleasure however the sensual pleasures have negative (addictive) results in the future.
Pleasure arises from the removal of disturbing craving (or otherwise physical pain) out of consciousness.
For example, in sex, there is the build up of agitating craving and that craving is 'released' or 'dispersed' in sexual climax. Thus the climax is the final pleasure sought. However, at a later time, that craving will return, often in a stronger way, which is called the cycle of addiction or samsara.
To the contrary, in meditation, craving is calmed away using concentration & the breathing. When various manifestations of craving called the 'five hindrances' are finally fully calmed & purified, the nervous system of the body breaks out in rapture (piti) & happiness (sukha). This process of rapture & happiness occurring as a result of calming the breathing & purifying the physical body is described in the Anapanasati teachings of the Pali Suttas.
In summary, all pleasure arises from the removal of disturbing agitating craving (or otherwise physical pain) out of consciousness. However, with sensual pleasure, it is only a 'suppression' or temporary 'shift' of craving. In meditation, it is the gradual 'dissolution' or 'purification' of craving. Therefore, meditation pleasure has no nasty addictive side effects and the pleasure is so much more sublime & refined (because there is no craving 'underlying' the pleasure).
